# How can I get this function to run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, netmiko

I am trying to run my python code, but the second function(see below.. `md5()`) does not work! Is this an error that I need to resolve?

**Connecting to device" 10.0.100.126 which image would you like to upload?yes
what would you like to name the image?testing
press enter to continue
Destination filename [testing]? UPLOADING.....................................

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from rashhad import yml
from keyboard import press
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

from test import image_name

with open('dev_devices.txt') as f:
    devices_list = f.read().splitlines()

for ip_address in devices_list:
    print('___________________________________________________________\n')
    print('Connecting to device" ' + ip_address)
    ios_device = {
        'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
        'ip': ip_address,
        'global_delay_factor': 4,
        "fast_cli": False,

    }

ios_device.update(yml('pass.yml', 'admin_a'))

cmd = "copy tftp://10.36.50.60/s2t54-ipservicesk9-mz.SPA.152-1.SY6.bin bootdisk:/"


def upload():
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**ios_device)
    net_connect.enable()
    firmware = input("which image would you like to upload?")
    if firmware == "yes":
        name = input("what would you like to name the image?")
        output = net_connect.send_command(cmd + name, delay_factor=4, expect_string=r'Destination filename')
        input("press enter to continue")
        press('enter')
        print(output)
        print("UPLOADING.....................................")
        net_connect.send_command("wr")
        net_connect.disconnect()


upload()

time.sleep(20)


def md5(): # This function does not run for some reason, I have no idea
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**ios_device)
    net_connect.enable()
    name = input("which image would you like to compare?")
    checksum = net_connect.send_command("verify /md5 bootdisk:" + name, delay_factor=4)
    print(checksum[-31:])
    net_connect.disconnect()



md5()
```

## Errors are below

```
Destination filename [testing]? 
UPLOADING.....................................
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rashhad.miah\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 699, in recv
    out = self.in_buffer.read(nbytes, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\rashhad.miah\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\paramiko\buffered_pipe.py", line 164, in read
    raise PipeTimeout()
paramiko.buffered_pipe.PipeTimeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rashhad.miah\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 569, in _read_channel_expect
    new_data = self.remote_conn.recv(MAX_BUFFER)
  File "C:\Users\rashhad.miah\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 701, in recv
    raise socket.timeout()
socket.timeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rashhad.miah\Desktop\netauto\test.py", line 41, in <module>
    upload()
  File "C:\Users\rashhad.miah\Desktop\netauto\test.py", line 37, in upload
    net_connect.send_command("wr")
  File "C:\Users\rashhad.miah\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\netmiko\utilities.py", line 430, in wrapper_decorator
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rashhad.miah\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 1490, in send_command
    new_data = self.read_until_pattern(pattern=re.escape(cmd))
  File "C:\Users\rashhad.miah\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 651, in read_until_pattern
    return self._read_channel_expect(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rashhad.miah\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 579, in _read_channel_expect
    raise NetmikoTimeoutException(
netmiko.ssh_exception.NetmikoTimeoutException: Timed-out reading channel, data not available.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? be specific. very specific. If there's an error message paste the _full_ error message into your question __as text__

Comment: I notice a `time.sleep(20)` before you call the function. Did you keep this in mind.

Comment: Hi Sorry, I am new to python and I have not used stack overflow before.

I have added the errors in the question, I would appreciate any help. 

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your exception stack trace indicates that it is failing on your `wr` execution in the upload function.

```
  File "C:\Users\rashhad.miah\Desktop\netauto\test.py", line 37, in upload
    net_connect.send_command("wr")
```

Do you even need that?

In particular it failed on the echo of that `wr` command i.e. Netmiko was expecting `wr` to be echoed and it never saw it:

```
packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 1490, in send_command
    new_data = self.read_until_pattern(pattern=re.escape(cmd))
```

You might want to look at the Netmiko session_log or Netmiko's debug log